# Opening angular materialdDialogs inside/with ngrx effect

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, ngrx, effects

I'm quite new to typescript/angular/ngrx development, so maybe my question sounds a little bit stupid...
Currently I'm developing a new application based on angular, angular material and ngrx.

As far as I read, if you are using redux you want to do as many things as possible in redux.
In my example: *Calling an angular material dialog with ngrx effects*

1. Do we want to have generic effects like openDialog, closeDialog, handleSave, handleCancel, etc.
2. Or do we want to open a dialog inside a component `this.dialog.open(MyDialogToOpen)` and
   handle only the response from the dialog inside an effect?

Currently im just playing around with my new application and new opportunities we got with angular and ngrx.
I tried to develop the generic solution but it is not working and i dont know why :(

In my component I call an effect openDialog

**shell.component.ts**

```
 const payload: OpenDialogPayload = {
        componentOrTemplateRef: ChangeUserSettingsComponent,
        config: {
            width: '250',
        },
    };

    this.store.dispatch(openDialog(payload));
```

**dialog.actions.ts**

```
export interface OpenDialogPayload {
componentOrTemplateRef: ComponentType<any>;
config?: MatDialogConfig;}

export const openDialog = createAction('[DIALOG] open dialog', props<OpenDialogPayload>());
```

**dialog.effects.ts**

```
    openDialog$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(openDialog),
        flatMap((action) => {
            const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(action.componentOrTemplateRef, {
                data: {},
            });
            return dialogRef.afterClosed();
        }),
    ),
);
```

Hint: If i remove in the props from the action and call the dialog directly inside the effect I guess it is working

The dialog is more or less opening:
[Dialog is opening on the left side with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tocna.png)

I literally tried everything. But I can not get it to work.
What is my mistake?
Is my complete approach wrong?
How do you handle your dialogs?

Thank you very much!
Sven

Answer (score 2):

Sure making your effect this way works

**dialog.effects.ts**

```
openDialog$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(openDialog),
        flatMap((action) => {
            const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ChangeUserSettingsComponent, {
                data: {},
            });
            return dialogRef.afterClosed();
        }),
    ),
);
```

But it wont be generic. Passing an anonym function to return your component should work, I had the same issue for my dialog effect. I am not able to find out why it works this way, nor if it is a good practice.

**shell.component.ts**

```
const payload: OpenDialogPayload = {
        componentOrTemplateRef: () => ChangeUserSettingsComponent,
        config: {
            width: '250',
        },
    };
```

But don't forget to call this function in your effect

**dialog.effects.ts**

```
openDialog$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(openDialog),
        flatMap((action) => {
            const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(action.componentOrTemplateRef(), {
                data: {},
            });
            return dialogRef.afterClosed();
        }),
    ),
);
```